# How to save browser session using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to write a python script which can change language of youtube and next time when I open browser using webdriver it show me youtube page in language which I saved before. Problem is my script is not working as expected and I am not sure why?

Selecting language and saving cookies in following code

```
url='https://www.youtube.com'
print(url)
#page = requests.get(url)

#open web browser
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
#load specific url
browser.get(url)
#wait to load js
time.sleep(5)
#find language picker and click
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yt-picker-language-button"]').click()
#wait to open language list
time.sleep(2)
#find and click specific language
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yt-picker-language-footer"]/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/button[1]').click()

pickle.dump(browser.get_cookies() , open("youtubeCookies.pkl","wb"))
```

Loading data from cookies.

```
url='https://www.youtube.com'
print(url)
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
for cookie in pickle.load(open("youtubeCookies.pkl", "rb")):
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
time.sleep(3)   
driver.refresh()
```

please guide me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you